# How can I efficiently write this derivative explanation if it is correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Basically, I am trying to prove that number $15$ relates to the graph of $D$, but I was wondering if my explanation was correct. Also, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of writing this, since I am repeating a lot and the graph doesn't have points on the axis.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYXQN.png]

Explanation: From the first interval, the function is increasing since the slope is positive, so $f ' > 0$. From the next interval, the function is decreasing since the slope is negative, so $f ' < 0$. From the third interval, the function is increasing, so $f ' > 0.$ From the fourth interval, the function is decreasing, so $f ' < 0.$ From the last interval, the function is increasing, so $f ' > 0.$ The graph the corresponds to this is $D$, because from the first interval, $f '$ is above zero on the $y -$ axis, from the second interval, $ f '$ is below zero on the $y -$ axis, from the third interval, $f '$ is above zero on the $y -$ axis, from the fourth interval, $f '$ is below zero on the $y -$ axis, and from the fifth interval, $f '$ is above zero on the y - axis.